# Sorting NSMutableArray ends with error

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm sorting a NSMutableArray that has NSString that contain numbers.
This is the code I'm using:

```
//creating mutable array
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"2", @"7", @"8", nil];

//sorting
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
}];

//logging
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

When I build Xcode highlights this piece of code with an error:
`}];` The error is:
 `Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'int (^)(struct NSString *, struct NSString *)', expected 'NSComparator'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `id` as the argument types to your block, rather than NSString. In Apple's [Short Practical Guide to Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html) it says:

> The Foundation framework declares the NSComparator type for comparing two items:
>
> ```
> typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);
> ```

Comment: Rather than add a reverser, just swap the order of the objects you compare, so use `[str2 compare:str1 options:...]`.